# How do I move inner HTML script to a seperate Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to clean up my code and currently the following scripts are in my HTML header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mobile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        TriggerClick2 = 0;
        $("#hamburger").click(function(){
            if(TriggerClick2==0){
                 TriggerClick2=1;
                 $("#navi").animate({width:'35%'}, 1000);
            }else{
                 TriggerClick2=0;
                 $("#navi").animate({width:'0%'}, 1000);
            };
          });
        }); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        TriggerClick = 0;
        $("#hamburger").click(function(){
            if(TriggerClick==0){
                 TriggerClick=1;
                 $(".content").animate({width:'65%'}, 1000);
            }else{
                 TriggerClick=0;
                 $(".content").animate({width:'100%'}, 1000);
            };
          });
        }); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".stayThere").mouseenter(function() {
            $('.moveThere').animate({'margin-left': '0%'}, 1000);
              }).mouseout(function() {
              $('.moveThere').animate({'margin-left': '-100%'}, 1000);
              });
            });
</script>
```

I understand that this is quite redundant but I'm a beginner and am still learning. What I'm trying to do is move this code to the mobile/js linked at the very top of the code.

What I have inside the mobile.js right now looks as follows

```
//initializes each function.
function init() {
    hideMenu();
    scaleContent();
    linkAnim1();
    linkAnim2();
    linkAnim3();
    linkAnim4();
    linkAnim5();
}

function hideMenu(){
    TriggerClick2 = 0;
    document.getElementById("hamburger").click(function(){
        if(TriggerClick2==0){
            TriggerClick2=1;
            document.getElementById("navi").animate({width:'35%'}, 1000);
        }else{
            TriggerClick2=0;
            document.getElementById("navi").animate({width:'0%'}, 1000);
        };
    });
};  

function scaleContent(){
    TriggerClick = 0;
    document.getElementById("hamburger").click(function(){
        if(TriggerClick==0){
            TriggerClick=1;
            document.getElementsByClassName("content").animate({width:'65%'}, 1000);
        }else{
            TriggerClick=0;
            document.getElementsByClassName("content").animate({width:'100%'}, 1000);
        };
    });
 }; 

 function linkAnim1(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("stayThere").mouseenter(function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('moveThere').animate({'margin-left': '0%'}, 1000);
             }).mouseout(function() {
                 document.getElementsByClassName('moveThere').animate({'margin-left': '-100%'}, 1000);
        });
};

//initializes the js functions above
window.onload = init;
```

sadly the moment I comment it out of the html document it stops doing anything altogether. To explain the functions, the first two are for mobile, bringing in the navigation while resizing the content, the other 5 are for each link Hover to animate a background image.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me with this as I need it for January 4th, until which my teachers are unavailable.

Thanks again and happy coding

Comment: I don't want someone to do my work for me... I just need help moving it out of the HTML into a seperate .js file... (the one that you see linked at the very top [mobile.js])

Comment: Well, look at how other your other external js files are pulled in, create a new one, link it, and paste the code into them.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this code... Can you please isolate an error specific for your question? Hint: Check the console.

Comment: Thank you Mark C. your earlier comment helped and works. I understand that there is a lot wrong but simply putting it into $(function() { //code }(); seemed to do the trick. I simply wanted to have it in it's own .js file instead of directly in the index.html Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I going to help you the best I can with out doing all of the work for you.

To begin you need only one document ready function for your script.

So take all of the JavaScript Code inside of the document ready functions and place it inside of a single document ready function.

Once you do that link to the JavaScript file by using the script tag right before your closing `</body>` tag in your html file.

Example(link to external JavaScript File):

```
<script src="myjavascriptfile.js"></script>
```

Note: The html code below assumes that your html file is in the same directory as the JavaScript.

Example(External JavaScript File Content):

```
$(document).ready(function(){//begin document closure


        TriggerClick2 = 0;
        $("#hamburger").click(function(){
            if(TriggerClick2==0){
                 TriggerClick2=1;
                 $("#navi").animate({width:'35%'}, 1000);
            }else{
                 TriggerClick2=0;
                 $("#navi").animate({width:'0%'}, 1000);
            };
          });


TriggerClick = 0;
        $("#hamburger").click(function(){
            if(TriggerClick==0){
                 TriggerClick=1;
                 $(".content").animate({width:'65%'}, 1000);
            }else{
                 TriggerClick=0;
                 $(".content").animate({width:'100%'}, 1000);
            };
          });

$(".stayThere").mouseenter(function() {
            $('.moveThere').animate({'margin-left': '0%'}, 1000);
              }).mouseout(function() {
              $('.moveThere').animate({'margin-left': '-100%'}, 1000);
              });

});//end document closure
```

Now with that being said there is a lot of things that may be going wrong with your code.  Posting your markup(HTML) will help with troubleshooting.

1. You are using global variables for your TriggerClick2, and TriggerClick one variables. Prefix them using the var keyword and place them at the top of the script inside of the document ready function.
2. You should try and get in the habit of using === instead of ==.  Using === evaluates to exactly equals(matches value and type) where == matches the value.  So if you want to make sure your matches the value and the variable type(number and string for example) then use === to prevent any potential headaches in the future.

Example:

```
var TriggerClick2 = 0;

var TriggerClick = 0;
```

Keep in mind that variables are scoped at the function level in JavaScript. So any variable that is declared inside of a function can not be accessed outside of the function it is declared in unless it returned by called a function that returns that variables value.